# How do I create a tricky HTML table with 3 columns and 4 rows?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table like this photo

[image]

I am confused about the rowspan.

Comment: You want without table structure ?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: i provide too you div structure you want may be using table not possible so

Comment: With structure like that photo example

Comment: <table border="1" style="width: 40%; border-spacing: 10px; box-shadow:5px 5px 10px 5px orange; background-color:cyan">
 <tr>
  <th style= "color:#seagreen; font-size:20px;" colspan="3"> Seasons </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td style= "width:20%; font-size:15px;" rowspan="2"> March/April </td>
     <th style= "width:15%; font-size:15px;" rowspan="3"> Spring </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> <strong> Cold </strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(fall.jpg)"> </td> </td>
  <td> Warm </td>
 </tr>
 
</table>

Comment: What problem in thi table ?

Comment: I put row span 3 for Spring but its not showing up properly and I don't know where to add the last box in my code for Warm (bold) with color background

Comment: All I see that you have two closing `</td>` after `background-image` table data.

Comment: If you see the table, it is just 3x3 table, not 4x3. You have to use spans to accommodate your td elements in those specific rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can test with a [online html table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables). This is what i tried (simple version, easy to understand, self-explanatory):

```html
<table border=1>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="6">Seasons</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">March/April</td>
   <td rowspan="5">spring</td>
   <td colspan="3">Cold</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">Warm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">picture</td>
   <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">Warm</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

So basically `rowspan` and `colspan` is what you need. Note that using a `rowspan` creates a block so the next table data `<td>` in the next row `<tr>` going to jump over.

Comment: Oopsi, Sorry, Is it obvius that im rookie here? :)

Comment: Yup, give it some time. It's just the flow and process which is created here.

Answer (score 0):

You have two columns in second row, it should have three columns. You can edit CSS for the table.

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 40%; border:1px; border-spacing: 10px; box-shadow:5px 5px 10px 5px orange; background-color:cyan">
  <tr>
    <th style="color:seagreen; font-size:20px;" colspan="3"> Seasons </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:20%; font-size:15px;" rowspan="2"> March/April </td>
    <td style="width:15%; font-size:15px;" rowspan="3"> Spring </td>
    <td>Cold</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EWarm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(fall.jpg)">
    </td>
    <td> Warm </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the table structure below, I used [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables#) website to generate it.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:15px 15px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:15px 15px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't want a generated table then create the using `colspan` and other table attributes, please read more about [HTML table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)